# Run Apigee X on GKE ingress

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, apigee

I'm looking to run APIGee X on GKE Ingress.

So let's say we have two backend services and one frontend service running on k8s. And ingress hostname is [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

1. "/" route to  frontend service.
2. /api/service1 route to  service1.
3. /api/service2 route to service2.

Now I have introduced apigee-x and it creates proxy to service1 and service2. But it can be called via api.example.com but our frontend only call [www.example.com/api](http://www.example.com/api). How to reverse proxy /api to apigee x. Also is it right approach ?

Comment: Can you check this [link](https://cloud.google.com/blog/products/application-modernization/connecting-apigee-to-gke-using-headless-services-and-cloud-dns) if this one can fit your requirement. This documentation is a guidance on how to connect your apigee to GKE using headless services and Cloud DNS.

Comment: I did read this, I didn't get it fully, it feels like it's opposite of what I am looking

Comment: I see, I found this [link](https://medium.com/@nanditasahu031/apigee-overview-and-set-up-of-apigee-x-92e7a963b81) on how to set up Apigee X. In this documentation there is a step on how to set up a reverse proxy. However since your tagging is under google cloud platform, be informed that this documentation is not a gcp documentation.

On the other hand I also see this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/develop/ui-create-proxy) on how to set up an API proxy.

Comment: Creating api proxy on apigee is something I am not looking for. Calling apigee x from gke is something I am looking for.

Comment: Is there any documentation that you are following or getting this idea that you can share?

Comment: Can you answer this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75638013/how-to-achieve-multi-tenancy-in-apigee

Answer (score 0):

For apigee X connection. There are two traffic essential directions. Northbound and Southbound. Northbound is incoming traffic to your apigee apis. Southbound is traffic which apigee sends to your backend etc as a part of your apigee proxy processing.

For apigee southbound end, ie outgoing connections from apigee X you need to configure [targets](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/deploy/load-balancing-across-backend-servers) and this [link](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/architecture/southbound-networking-patterns)

For northbound traffic, ie incoming traffic to apigee, please see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/apigee/docs/api-platform/system-administration/peering-ranges#:%7E:text=the%20Customer%20VPC%3A-,Northbound,-traffic%3A%20API%20proxy) which gives an overview

Comment: For northbound traffic,  how to connect from kubernetes ?