# How to achieve multi tenancy in Apigee

Tags: google-cloud-platform, api-gateway, apigee

I have dedicated backend servers to each tenant. I want to redirect
Api calls to right tenant server. These are probable solution I can think of

- When creating developer registeration add tenant info as custom attribute. And use it in proxy. (This has disadvantage that a developer represents tenant)
- another solution is app can have custom attribute which have tenant info. (this has disadvantage that if developer have many apps)
- developer start passing tenant name in request header (but then how to ensure that he shouldn't be allowed for unauthorised tenant)
- creating different proxy for each tenant can be a another solution. (This has disadvantage that we have to create product for each tenant)
- create different environment for each tenant
- create different org for each tenant (mostly I don't want to create different org and similarly different environment for each tenant. Although I want to understand what can be the disadvantages of this)

Main question,  is there any standard solution? Is it even right approach?